# CSS Grid System not working as thought

Tags: html, css

```css
/* Responsive Styling */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

/* Body CSS */
/* Header */

#header {
 height: 70px;
 background-color:white;
 border-top: solid 5px #324f8e;
 border-bottom: solid 2px #d5dae7;
 }
 
.logo {
 background-image: url('images/logo.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 15px;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }
 
.search {
 backr
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<div class="col-5 logo"></div>
<input type="search" class="col-2 search" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
<div class="ool-2 account"></div>
<div class="ool-1 notification"></div>
<div class="ool-2 logout"></div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

I can't seem to make the search be in the header container after the logo. I want it all to be in line for the header bar. I'm trying to use the Grid system, it's something small I suppose, but as a newbie, it's not clicking to me.

Also having issues with the logo, it seems to cut off slightly on the bottom, tried to a few different things with height, no luck on that either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeaaa, just so you know, this isn't the css `grid` system. But also, please put your work in a fiddle ( or something similar ) so others can easily poke around.

Comment: Any recommendations for the right grid system? Picked this off W3schools I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your header:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(x, 1fr);
```

Change the x by the number of elements you want in a single line.

This article could be helpful:
[CSS Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)